# Ajax is undefined and throws runtime exception

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, rest

```
    ajax.postJson(
                "/foo/GetFoo",
                { fooName: fooName },
                function (data) {

                },
                function (error) {  });
        };

My Rest api call is GetAsync()
```

It throws ajax is undefined : JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'exceptionStart' of undefined or null reference. The custom code to make ajax call is below. The api call Getfoo is GetAsync method using attribute HttpGet. Can someone point me to the cause of this failure

```
var ajax = {

    defaultAjaxTimeout: 600000,
    exceptionStart: '<!--',
    exceptionEnd: '-->',

    postJson: function (url, data, success, error) {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                dateType: "json",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                timeout: ajax.defaultAjaxTimeout,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (success) success(result);
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (error && jqXhr) {
                        var responseText = jqXhr.responseText;
                        var index = responseText.indexOf(ajax.exceptionStart);
                        if (index > 0) {
                            var exception = responseText.substr(index + ajax.exceptionStart.length + 1);
                            index = exception.lastIndexOf(ajax.exceptionEnd);
                            if (index > 0) {
                                exception = exception.substr(0, index);
                            }
                            error(exception);
                        } else {
                            error(errorThrown);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    },
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code one line at a time?

Comment: Yes the issues is at var index = responseText.indexOf(ajax.exceptionStart); where ajax is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having here is that you're attempting to access the variable `ajax` from a closure before it's created:

```
var myVariable = {
    myProperty: "Hello",
    myFunction: function () {
        //... access myVariable.myProperty -> error
    }
};
```

There are two options here. The cleaner one, and the one I'd use is this:

```
var ajaxOptions = {
    defaultAjaxTimeout: 600000,
    exceptionStart: '<!--',
    exceptionEnd: '-->'
};
var ajax = {
    postJson: function (url, data, success, error) {
        ... ajaxOptions.exceptionStart.length
    }
};
```

The reason this works is because `ajaxOptions` exists already in the scope where you declare the function `ajax.postJson` so it's able to reference it correctly from its closure.

The variation on this option is this:

```
var ajax = {
    defaultAjaxTimeout: 600000,
    exceptionStart: '<!--',
    exceptionEnd: '-->'
};
ajax.postJson = function (url, data, success, error) {
    ... ajax.exceptionStart.length
};
```

The reason this works is because `ajax` is already declared, and is just attached to the closure of the function.

A second, less-clean option is to put the `ajax` variable as a child of the `window` object:

```
window.ajax = {

    defaultAjaxTimeout: 600000,
    exceptionStart: '<!--',
    exceptionEnd: '-->',

    postJson: function (url, data, success, error) {
        ... window.ajax.exceptionStart.length
    }
};
```

The reason this works is because `window` always exists in all lexical scopes, so it'll have no problem referencing it. The reason it's less clean is because it pollutes the window object and any JavaScript anywhere on your page can access and change it, potentially causing unknown behavior. I'm not recommending it, I'm just providing it as an example.

Comment: Will try your solution and mark it as correct . Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

The following steps helped me resolve similar problem, I used IE11
the solution to it in IE 11 can be:

1. under internet settings select 'Compatibility View settings',
2. in 'Add this website' enter server name for your website (for example: localhost ), click 'Add' btn.
3. Tick 'Display intranet steps in Compatibility View' box.